# VirtualBox VM wouldn't start

Tags: virtualbox

This is my first time playing with the VirtualBox CLI. I'm trying to start a VM and then connect directly to its shell. I'm trying the following:

```
ram@nope:~/VirtualBox VMs> vboxmanage startvm my-machine --type headless   
Waiting for VM "my-machine" to power on...                                     
VM "my-machine" has been successfully started.                                 
ram@nope:~/VirtualBox VMs> vboxmanage guestcontrol my-machine run bash     
VBoxManage: error: Machine "my-machine" is not running (currently powered off)!
```

This is really frustrating because it's saying the machine was started, but then it doesn't work, with no error message.

Also, is my second message the appropriate one to connect to the shell in the guest? I basically want the same shell that's displayed to a user running the VM from the VirtualBox GUI. I also want to be able to script this and push commands automatically to the VM in a script.

Comment: Your virtualbox must be 5. Is it?

Comment: @alicanakyol Yes, I believe I installed the most recent version.

Comment: Well I think your virtualbox closed immediately.

Comment: I need to know how to solve the problem.